# deploy maven project to tomcat with gitlab ci

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

i want to deploy project maven to tomcat with gitlab ci
but maven is not able to download anything from central
I have a Maven project which contains  Java test classes and main classes. I use mvn clean compile  $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS command to compile it is working . Now I want to deploy this project into tomcat7.

```
`mvn install tomcat7:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.2/maven-war-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.5.3/maven-release-plugin-2.5.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.5.3
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin/2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:jar:2.2
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/maven-war-plugin/maven-war-plugin/3.2.2/maven-war-plugin-3.2.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for maven-war-plugin:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2: Plugin maven-war-plugin:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for maven-war-plugin:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.2.2
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.252 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-16T14:46:35+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/zKrRyGN3/0/root/test/./.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

### pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.dep</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-maven-dep</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>simple-maven-dep</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<build>

<pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
  <url>http://myipadress:8081/manager/text</url>

    <path>/webapp</path>
      <update>true</update>
    <username>admin</username>
     <password>admin</password>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
   <plugin>
  
<groupId>maven-war-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.2</version>
           <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>

</project>
```

### setting.xml

```
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

         
<servers>
<server>
<id>tomcat</id>
<username>admin</username>
<password>adminadmin</password>  
</server>
</servers>


        <pluginGroups>

    <pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
      </pluginGroups>
  
</settings>
```

---

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmaven.repo.local=./.m2/repository"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"

cache:
  paths:
    - ./.m2/repository
  # keep cache across branch
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "mvn clean compile  $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS "
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - "mvn install tomcat7:deploy"
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.wa
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to proxy settings. Please enable proxy in "**settings.xml**" and pass the values accordingly. You can verify proxy setting from your local machine, That is,

**IE setting->LAN Settings**

Then copy the Address as host and port as the port and check again.

To enable a proxy setting in settings.xml

```
<!-- proxy
 | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.

<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>345325</username>
  <password>dfgasdfg</password>
  <host>proxy.abc.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>proxy.abc.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
|-->    ----------REMOVE THIS LINE AND CLOSE It above <proxy> tag
```